# How cell reference is useful in the calculation?

Tags: excel

When We write any formula, for specific function, we need to direct excel the specific location of that data. This location is referred as, Cell Reference. We know very well but how this useful and in which scenario it can be used ?

Comment: What happens if you take a web-search about `Excel Cell Reference`? For me this leads to thousands of Excel tutorials which all are writing about usage of cell references in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Cell references are way better than replicating a formula many times. It would be simple if you have a small spreadsheet, but what about thousands of complex computations? It is also better as it creates a more automated spreadsheet, such that when one value is changed other values automatically change.